# Missing folder and files from visual studio. not even showing in Project

Tags: c#

I am missing two folders and number of files in the visual studio 2019 from my project. All these files are showing in the local commit. I tried to recover it and also tried to push to GitHub but got some errors. Is there any way to recover folders and files?
Can someone help please

Thankyou

Comment: What happened between having the files/folder and them disappearing?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include relevant tags. Just because you're using C# and Visual Studio 2019 doesn't automatically make this a [tag:c#] question.

Comment: As for the question itself: What errors did you get? We'd be able to point you in the right direction a little bit easier if we knew what happened when you tried to push to GitHub.

Comment: Did you tried to toggle "Show All Files" in Solution Explorer?

Answer (score 2):

If you right click on your Project, goto `Add` -> `Existing Item...` and select the missing Folders/Files from the explorer select window.

Comment: Thankyou for reply 
The missing folders and files are not in my project even not in the computer.
These files are showing in Local commit when we select Changes from Team Explorer.

Comment: if you are using git then I would suggest looking at `git status` and `git stash show -p` which will show the contents of the most recent stash. It sounds like you committed / staged the files but then they were removed/deleted